# Spring MVC Ajax form properties name

Tags: ajax, json, spring, spring-mvc, controller

I have a form with a list of fields:

```
type, name, description, height ,width
```

I send by **`ajax`** to my **`controller`**, my `controller` receive this `ajax` call but he said that all input fields are `null`.

My mapped **`DTO`** have the same fields but with `distinct` name, really I don't need use the same name in my call `ajax` that in my `@RequestBody` `dto` `class`.

Its possible? I am limited to use same names in the *class* and the *ajax calls*?

This aren't a problem really, but I can't found any info about this.

My **`DTO`** properties:

```
 ResourceCreateDTO [resourceTypeId=null, resourceId=null, 
 resourceName=null, resourceDescription=null, folderId=null]
```

My **JSON** data:

```
resource-description: "asdfasdfasdfasdfsadfasdfsdfasdfasdfasdfasdfsadfasdfasdf"
resource-folder: "0"
resource-folder-type: "1000"
resource-id: "1006"
resource-name: "asdfasdfasdfasdf"
```

My **AJAX Call**:

```
$("#createModalSubmit").click(function(){

        var data = {};

        $('#createForm *').filter(':input').each(function(){
              var input = $(this);
              data[input.attr("name")] = input.val();
              delete data["undefined"];
        });

        $.ajax({
            contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            type: "POST",
            url: context + "/editor/create",
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            dataType : 'json',
            cache: false,
            success:function(result){
            },
            error:function(){
            }
        });
});
```

My `Controller` config:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/editor/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody ResourceDTO create(@RequestBody ResourceCreateDTO dto)
            throws Exception {

        System.out.println("dto: " + dto.toString());
```

This system out prints the above **DTO** toString.

I am searching any type of anotation or config that I can name the **DTO** properties:

```
@MyCustomName("resource-name")
private String resourceName;
```

Use my "*resource-name*" from the **AJAX** call.

Comment: show controller method and ajax call

Answer (score 1):

If your DTO cannot have the same name that is being used in your ajax, you can then match it manually inside your controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/editor/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody ResourceDTO create(@RequestBody String dto)
        throws Exception {
    //mapping
}
```

Or

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/editor/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody ResourceDTO create(@RequestBody Map<String,Object> dto)
        throws Exception {
    //mapping
}
```